# TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null

Tags: null, discord.js, embed

My discord bot was working fine and working exactly how I wanted it to. But now when I run the bot, it runs for a couple of minutes and then crashes with this error

```js
if (embed.title.includes("Raid") && embed.fields[1].value.includes("5 minutes left")) {

TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null
```

Here is my current code that is running!

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.id === '432616859263827988') {
    if (message.embeds.length == 1) {
      const embed = message.embeds[0]
      if (embed.title.includes("Raid") && embed.fields[1].value.includes("5 minutes left")) {
        return  message.channel.send('<@&777249060293443595> Raid Time!')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I have tried looking up similar issues, but I just can't get my bot to stay online and stable. If I need to add more info let me know!
Thanks!

Comment: The error indicates that either `embed.title` is `null` or `embed.fields[1].value` is `null`. Can you `console.log` both values and check which one is `null`? That would help us help you

Comment: Yeah I definitely can! I'll try looking it up how to do that unless you see this first and let me know how to, sorry I am pretty new trying to figure things out. I'll reply back soon! Thanks!

Comment: Alright! so it looks like the `embed.title` is returning as `null`, this happens when another message from the same ID is sent that does not contain the title field. 
So would there be a way to edit my code to fix that?

Comment: You can just check if it exists in the previous `if` statement. `if (message.embeds.length === 1 && message.embeds[0].title && message.embeds[0].fields[1])`

Comment: I made the change and that worked out great! Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short solution. Just add `?`

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.id === '432616859263827988') {
    if (message.embeds.length == 1) {
      const embed = message.embeds[0]
      if (embed.title?.includes("Raid") && embed.fields[1]?.value?.includes("5 minutes left")) {
        return  message.channel.send('<@&777249060293443595> Raid Time!')
      }
    }
  }
})
```